# Git log current branch messages only in order of commits

Tags: git, branch, message, commit

Find a way to get only the git commit messages but only from the current branch and also in the order of commits.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, for example:
If your branch is a branch from the develop branch you could run:

```
git log --no-merges --count HEAD ^develop --reverse --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

Comment: I added some formatting to this to make it output a bulleted list with linebreaks: `git log --no-merges HEAD ^develop --reverse --pretty="format:* %s%n%b" --abbrev-commit`

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --first-parent your_branch_name --reverse
```

where `--first-parent` - will show the commit messages but only from the `your_branch_name` branch
, `--reverse` - use a messages order which will display the commits from oldest on top to the most recent at the bottom.